# Multiple query in one query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question:

Does it possible to collect multiple query in one query?

i.e in a Form I have 10 query like this:

```
1.  SELECT ThisValue FROM thatTable1 WHERE
2.  SELECT ThisValue FROM thatTable2 WHERE
                 .......
10.      SELECT ThisValue FROM thatTable10 WHERE
```

where should I write i.e this code in Access.It it possible in Access or only I can do that in MS SQL and....

```
CREATE PROC dbo.proc_app_CollectControlData
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      CONTROLNAME   nvarchar(74),
      CONTROLVALUE  nvarchar(255)
    )

    -- Now we collect the data for the 10 different controls
    INSERT INTO @t
    (CONTROLNAME, CONTROLVALUE)
    SELECT 'MyFirstControl',
            ThisValue
    FROM dbo.ThatTable
    WHERE Condition1

    ...

    INSERT INTO @t
    (CONTROLNAME, CONTROLVALUE)
    SELECT 'MyTenthControl',
            ThisValue
    FROM dbo.ThatTable
    WHERE Condition10

    -- And now we return all found data to the client
    SELECT * FROM @
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

```
SELECT  'MyFirstControl' AS ControlName, ThisValue AS ControlValue
FROM    thatTable1 
WHERE   Condition1 
UNION ALL
SELECT  'MySecondControl' AS ControlName, ThisValue AS ControlValue
FROM    thatTable2
WHERE   Condition2
UNION ALL
SELECT  'MyThirdControl' AS ControlName, ThisValue AS ControlValue
FROM    thatTable3
WHERE   Condition3
```

Comment: Why not UNION ALL? This is perfect for the requirements you have given. It is not very helpful to ask how something can be done, then when you are told a way it can be done specify you need it done a different way. If you did not want it done using `UNION`/`UNION ALL` then you should have secified that in your question.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/e3acc5af-1bd9-42de-93f1-209f4dfc11ed/#2b9484a2-9b58-4048-a57e-85e515477c8e

Comment: Does it possible to impement the above idea in Access?

Comment: Again, why not `UNION`?. I understand that someone has given you a SQL-Server solution that doesn't use `UNION` so you want to translate this to Access, however that is not really a valid reason. What I am saying is if you can acheive the result you require by using `UNION`, then why not use `UNION`? `UNION ALL` would arguably a better solution than table varibales, even if Access supported them.

Comment: and Performance,which one is better? UNION ALL or  table variables? may be I should change the Title,Can I use Table variable in Access?

Comment: If you are using the Access Database engine, then no, table variables are not supported. There are workarounds, such as having permanent tables that can be inserted to, selected from and then deleted, using `UNION` is almost certainly going to be a better solution. I cannot say for definite which would perform better in SQL-Server, table variables or UNION, testing and checking execution plans is the the best way to answer this. This seems like a moot point though if you are using Access.

Comment: So thank you. I have a Form in Access that contains c.a 10 controls and each of them have a query ( SELECT ....)  Can Use a one **UNION** select instead of ten queris. and does it improve my performance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11516/discussion-between-garethd-and-iav-babak)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ThisValue FROM thatTable1 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ThisValue FROM thatTable2 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ThisValue FROM thatTable10 WHERE ...
```

Comment: Not UNIONALL .I want another way

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on why you don't want to use an operator that has specifically been designed to do what you are asking?

Comment: somthing like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/e3acc5af-1bd9-42de-93f1-209f4dfc11ed/#2b9484a2-9b58-4048-a57e-85e515477c8e)